# Blue Smoke coming from exhaust of scooter after a month of engine rebuild

Tags: engine, oil-leak, scooter

Recently i had an oil change and  a month ago had my engine half rebuild.But now,Blue smoke is coming from exhaust.I suspected oil leaking inside engine but due to worn out piston but since its recently rebuild I decided to check and removed the exhaust and found no smoke was coming.I realized the exhaust is all filled with oil inside .But then again How did so much oil stuck on the exhaust?

Comment: which half of the engine was rebuilt?

Comment: I don't know but the mechanic says two options half engine rebuild and full engine rebuild.must be related to the number or parts replacement inside engine

Comment: So which bits did you pay for?

Comment: Is this a 2-stroke or a 4-stroke scooter engine?  On a 4-stroke the valve guides (top half) or the piston rings (bottom half) are most likely sources of your blue smoke.  On a 2-stroke it's more likely related to the oil injection system.  But without additional information from you, it's just guessing.

Comment: It's two stroke.

Comment: Yes I also thought that there must be oil leak in engine due to worn off piston but since I just changed the piston a month ago I don't think it's inside engine.

Comment: I think at some point  a few days ago I overfilled the engine oil during engine oil change momentarily and started engine for a moment but I quickly saw it and removed excess oil at that time.

Comment: So I think at that moment some overfilled engine oil got into my exhaust and now it's coming out of exhaust. By burning since my exhaust is all full of oil